# Blender on Mac: how to do right click using left click (lmb)?

Tags: osx

in Mac , i can do 'right click' by using 'Ctrl' + LMB. It works on finder or browser but this Ctrl LMB doesn't work inside blender or brush. I need to do it by using left button (lmb) because the digitizer pen only has 1 button.

For now, I have to use mouse or touchpad /trackpad to do 'right click'. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to press the trackpad with two fingers to emulate a right click. If it doesn't work, go to System Preferences/Trackpad/Point and Click and make sure Secondary Click is set to Two Fingers.

Comment: Thanks but The problem is when using blender on my ipad pro wirelessly ( i use easycanvas pro + tablet pro). Let say, the laptop is away from me, i don't have access to keyboard and trackpad. when two fingers tap on ipad, it is not registered as Right click.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac (Book), you can open the Object Context Menu by pressing  <kbd>W</kbd>.